# Check in JSF EL what severity messages are shown

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I want to know what kind of messages are shown in the current page using EL. I'm particularly interested in errors above warning severity. 
My current solution is this:

```
#{ facesContext.getMaximumSeverity().getOrdinal() ge 2}
```

But i want a better one (safer and more explicit), something like this:

```
#{facesContext.getMaximumSeverity() != null and facesContext.getMaximumSeverity().compareTo(facesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN)>0}
```

The problem is that i can't get any value out of facesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until the upcoming [EL 3.0](https://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/StaticField), you can't reference constants in EL.

As to open source libraries, the only one which can help you in this is [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org). It offers a [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) tag for the very purpose.

```html
<o:importConstants type="javax.faces.application.FacesMessage" />
```

This way you'll be able to use

```
#{facesContext.maximumSeverity eq FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR or facesContext.maximumSeverity eq FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL}
```

or

```
#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.compareTo(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN) gt 0}
```

or

```
#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.compareTo(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR) ge 0}
```

or

```
#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal gt FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN.ordinal}
```

or

```
#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal ge FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.ordinal}
```

*(note that I omitted the unnecessary `get` prefix and `()` parens, IDE-autocomplete in EL doesn't necessarily generate right and clean code)*

Comment: Thank you. I really like the last solution: #{facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal ge FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.ordinal}

Comment: If you're stuck with JSF 1.2, Apache's Unstandard library also allows similar access to constants. https://blog.tallan.com/2010/07/01/the-unstandard-tag-library-using-constants-within-jsps/