# Richfaces validation error on oncomplete script

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

i have the jsfunction

```
<a4j:jsFunction action="#{myBean.action}"
  data="#{myBean.data}" render="@form" execute="@form" name="openConfirm"  
onbeforedomupdate="openConfirmDialog(event.data);"></a4j:jsFunction>
```

I need open a confirm dialog(on the onbeforedomupdate, this works.. but open the dialog for all calls) I really need open the dialog form only if the jsf submit was validated. the validation errors shows when the form was not validated.

Whats the best way, to identify in the script if the JSF cycle returns validations errors?

i need something similar to onbeforedomupdate="if (event.validationError==false)showDialog();"

thanks a lot,

Comment: You can check for error like `if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null})`. In case if you have error, warning, info you can use `#{empty facesContext.messageList}` for checking validation messages before show dialog.

Comment: thanks Vasil, but this is a server side expression, how i use this expression with jsFunction?

Comment: No, it is client side checking. Use it like `onbeforedomupdate="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null}) { openConfirmDialog(event.data); }"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for error like this

```
if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null}) { openConfirmDialog(event.data); }
```

In case if you have more than 1 type of messages (error, warning, info) you can use

```
if (#{empty facesContext.messageList}) { openConfirmDialog(event.data); }
```

for checking validation messages before showing the dialog.

Example of usage in `oncomplete`:

```
oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null}) {#{rich:component('popup')}.show();}"
```

In case you want to react on warnings and errors but not on info messages use

```
oncomplete="if(#{facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal gt 0}) {#{rich:component('popup')}.show();}"
```

Additional information about last case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856966/check-in-jsf-el-what-severity-messages-are-shown).